# How to query a file using C++ on IBM AS/400

Tags: c++, ibm-midrange

How can I query a physical file on a IBM AS/400 system located on a IBM AS/400 system.

When doing this with RPG/400 it's quite simple:

- Define my `logical file` in the `File Definitions`
- Define my KeyList
- SETLL or CHAIN with the KeyList and
- READ or READE with KeyList

But how can I archieve the same thing using a C++ source file on a AS/400 system? I didn't find anything usefull on IBM's `https://publib.boulder.ibm.com`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "query" ? The usual verbs are read and write. And the steps given suggest you have a `READ`. That would suggest a straightforward `std::ifstream`, just as your C++ book tells you.

Comment: "query" means looping through the "database" like reading all data where the customer id equals the value from a field in a display file

Comment: Any reason not to use SQL? You can use the _Rxxxxx() Library functions; but if you want WHERE customerId = :dspfValue, SQL might be easier.

Comment: It's not just all about querying, but also displaying DDS records, processing data and so on

Comment: And what part of that (including "...and so on"), can't be done via SQL in C++? There are some fairly rare file definitions that can be created in AS/400s (and in all of the systems that came later in that line) and that SQL can't process, but they'd be unusual to run into nowadays. If you have any, they should be replaced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not quite as easy since C++ doesn't have RPGLE's native support of DB tables.

The docs are here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahg/rzahgcandcplus.htm

The ILE C/C++ Runtime Library functions include the `_Rxxxxx()` functions used for Record level access in C/C++.  A sample:

- _Ropen() — Open a Record File for I/O Operations
- _Rreadk() — Read a Record by Key
- _Rlocate() — Position a Record

The related Information link includes a link to the ILE C?C++ Programmer's guide that you'll probably want to start with.

The programmer's Guide includes a chapter talking about file system access (IFS and DB Table).  There are two options discussed for bringing in a tables external description into your C/C++ program.

- Generate C/C++ Source (GENCSRC) utility to generate database header files
- `#pragma mapinc` directive

Personally, I'm not sure why you'd want to use C/C++ to do DB access.  With ILE, it would be easy to call RPGLE procedures doing the I/O from a C/C++ program.

Comment: so you mean that it would be better to write a C++ programm that just comsumes/calls a RPGLE programm which does my I/O operations (reading the database)?

Comment: Yes, assuming that there's some need for C++ in the first place; for instance, trying to port existing code.